# abcjs cursorControl example with wrong target assign

Tags: javascript, vue.js, abcjs

I'd followed the instruction on abcjs Example Generator and ebbed this code to my page. But if I click on play, I got the linter error 'target is undefinded'. If I understand is the visualObj not correct to the visual canvas assigned, but I don't find a smart way to do this.

Has anyone expirience with abcjs and have a tipp for me?

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container-sm">
    <div v-for="item in songData" :key="item.id">
      <div>
        <h6>musik > <router-link to="songsearch">genre</router-link><router-link to="songsearch"> > {{ table }}</router-link></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <ul class="unstyled-list list-inline">
          <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
          <li class="list-inline-item">{{ item.title }}</li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn bg-transparent" @click="showAbc">show ABC-Text</button>
      </div>
      <div id="abc-code" class="text-center" style="display: none;">
<textarea class="abc-string" id="abcString" v-model="item.chords" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div id="audio" class="text-center"></div>
      <div id="midi" class="midi-download"></div>
      <div id="paper" class="text-center"></div>
      <div id="download_btn"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
import 'abcjs/abcjs-audio.css'
import abcjs from 'abcjs'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      table: this.$route.query.table,
      song: this.$route.query.song,
      songData: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getSong().then(() => {
      this.loadABC()
    });
  },
  methods: {
    async getSong() {
      let apiURL = 'https://gracile-software.de/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxx-api/songattic/xxx.php';
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('table', this.table);
      formData.append('song', this.song);
      try {
        let loadSong = await this.axios.post(apiURL, formData);
        this.songData = loadSong.data;
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    },
    loadABC() {
      let options = {};
      const visualObj = new abcjs.Editor("abcString", {
        canvas_id: "paper",
        abcjsParams: options,
        synth: {
          el: "#audio",
          options: {
            displayLoop: true,
            displayRestart: true,
            displayPlay: true,
            displayProgress: true,
            displayWarp: true
          },
        },
      });
      var cursorControl = new CursorControl("#paper");
      document.querySelector(".abcjs-midi-start").addEventListener("click", startTimer);
      function onEvent(ev) {
        if (ev)
          cursorControl.onEvent(ev);
          else
          cursorControl.onFinished();
      }
      function startTimer() {
        cursorControl.onStart();
        var timingCallbacks = new abcjs.TimingCallbacks(visualObj[0], {
        eventCallback: onEvent
        });
        timingCallbacks.start();
      }
      function CursorControl(rootSelector) {
        var self = this;
        self.cursor = null; // This is the svg element that will move with the music.
        self.rootSelector = rootSelector; // This is the same selector as the renderAbc call uses.

        self.onStart = function() {
            var svg = document.querySelector(self.rootSelector + " svg");
            self.cursor = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
            self.cursor.setAttribute("class", "abcjs-cursor");
            self.cursor.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', 0);
            self.cursor.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', 0);
            self.cursor.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', 0);
            self.cursor.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', 0);
            svg.appendChild(self.cursor);
        };

        self.removeSelection = function() {
            var lastSelection = document.querySelectorAll(self.rootSelector + " .abcjs-highlight");
            for (var k = 0; k < lastSelection.length; k++)
                lastSelection[k].classList.remove("abcjs-highlight");
        };
        self.onEvent = function(ev) {

            // This is called every time a note or a rest is reached and contains the coordinates of it.
            if (ev.measureStart && ev.left === null)
                return; // this was the second part of a tie across a measure line. Just ignore it.

            self.removeSelection();

            // Select the currently selected notes.
            for (var i = 0; i < ev.elements.length; i++ ) {
                var note = ev.elements[i];
                for (var j = 0; j < note.length; j++) {
                    note[j].classList.add("abcjs-highlight");
                }
            }

            // Move the cursor to the location of the current note.
            if (self.cursor) {
                self.cursor.setAttribute("x1", ev.left - 2);
                self.cursor.setAttribute("x2", ev.left - 2);
                self.cursor.setAttribute("y1", ev.top);
                self.cursor.setAttribute("y2", ev.top + ev.height);
            }
        };
        self.onFinished = function() {
                self.removeSelection();
            if (self.cursor) {
                self.cursor.setAttribute("x1", 0);
                self.cursor.setAttribute("x2", 0);
                self.cursor.setAttribute("y1", 0);
                self.cursor.setAttribute("y2", 0);
            }
        };
      }
    },
    showAbc() {
      let abcCode = document.getElementById("abc-code");
      if(abcCode.style.display == "none") {
        abcCode.style.display = "block";
      }else {
        abcCode.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.abc-string {
  width: 26em;
  height: 18em;
  resize: none;
}
.abcjs-highlight {
fill: #0a9ecc;
}
.abcjs-cursor {
stroke: red;
}
</style>
```

An active runing sample you can see here: https://gracile-software.de/projects/ZDF_Mark_New/

Click on the dice and choose a song to see the player.

Comment: which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: at line:       var timingCallbacks = new abcjs.TimingCallbacks(visualObj[0]

Comment: you don't seem to have any element with the class `abcjs-midi-start`, so there is no target for the click handler.

Comment: This Element is in the generated Midi Player.